# Why is this code crashing an iOS app with "Out Of Memory"?

Tags: xamarin.ios

My question originally dealt with a string loaded from disk and my app runing out of memory but there's a much simpler way to make it crash and I don't understand why. Run the code below and it will die within seconds (iPad 4.2).
In theory it should just run forever. No references are kept to the large StringBuilder and it is set to NULL immediately.
If I watch it in Instruments, memory goes up to 160MB after a few loops and the app will die. Why is the memory not released?
Each loop increases memory by about 10MB...

One thought is that GC just can't keep up but it does not matter how big the delay in Thread.Sleep() is - eventually, memory will be gone.

The test might look academic but I have an issue with a real app which is crashing. It has a method which gets a (huge) string back from a WebService request, converts that string into an XmlDocument and parses it (stores something to DB). Then the method exits but memory stays high. If I execute the same method again (an hour later or so!), the app dies OOM. Why is the memory still alloced?

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching ( UIApplication app, NSDictionary options )
        {
            Thread oThread = new Thread ( DoIt );
            oThread.Start (  );

            return true;
        }

        public void DoIt ()
        {
            using(var o = new NSAutoreleasePool())
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    StringBuilder oSB = new StringBuilder();
                    for(int i = 0; i < 800000; ++i)
                    {
                        oSB.Append("1234567890");
                    }
                    oSB = null;
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }
```

**EDIT**: I noticed that if I change the Do() method like shown below, memory remains stable. It goes up for a while, then GC kicks in and cleans it. If I add an s.Dispose() after creating the NSString object, memory won't go up at all.
So it seems to be an issue with .NET string classes.

```
public void DoIt ()
            {
                using(var o = new NSAutoreleasePool())
                {
                                StringBuilder oSB = new StringBuilder();
                    for(int i = 0; i < 800000; ++i)
                    {
                        oSB.Append("1234567890");
                    }
                    while(true)
                    {
                            NSString s = new NSString(oSB.ToString());  
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The StringBuilder internally allocates new larger arrays on each iteration (It might be doubling in size).   Eventually, you will end up with a fragmented heap.

Comment: But what is the correct way then when I have to deal with strings I need to concatenate? Can I somehow force GC to defrag the heap? And why is it only happening on the device but not in the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

maybe text is uncompressed on memory

Comment: I changed the question. It has nothing to do with uncompressing.